How are inactive identification questions currently handled by the system?
Back in 2015, a meta discussion marked status-completed ("has been resolved through the implementation of a feature") led to: "Extend the policy for deleting inactive identification questions". The agreed-upon rule, based on Flyk's proposal, was to delete any identification question inactive for 30 days and without any upvoted or accepted answers. However, it's unclear how this rule was actually put into action. Was it automated through adjustments to Roomba (the system that handles automatic question deletion), or was it something enforced manually by the community and moderators?
Up until July 2024, I've observed that moderators often delete ID questions immediately after closure, rather than waiting the full 30 days. This suggests a change in approach, and it's unclear whether Roomba is enforcing the original 30-day deletion policy.
To clarify, here's a summary of how the standard Roomba deletion process works, according to the Meta SE post, "How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?":


The system will automatically delete closed, unlocked, and non-migrated questions that have zero or negative score, have no positively-scored or accepted answers, have no pending reopen votes, were closed for any reason other than duplicate nine or more days ago, and haven't been edited in the past nine days. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedClosed" in the question timeline)




The system will automatically delete negatively-scored, non-migrated, unlocked, and unanswered questions (both open and closed, including as duplicates) that are older than 30 days. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveDeadQuestions" in the question timeline)




The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions older than 365 days on main (non-meta) sites, that have a score of zero (or have a score of 1 and the owner's account is deleted), have fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments. (shown as "Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedQuestions" in the question timeline)


Considering we recently re-allowed ID questions after they were banned in 2018, is this 2015 30-day ID question deletion policy still active? If it is, does Roomba currently enforce it as outlined in the original proposal? If not, it might be a good idea to remove the status-completed tag from that meta post and update it to accurately reflect the current process. It would be great to get some clarity on this, as it impacts how we manage older ID questions on the site.

Roomba never enforced any of this. We didn't have anything automatic installed by SE (how could we anyway?). So unless there's moderators with a particular interest in going the extra mile for keeping the site clean manually, there's no real cause for panic. ;-)

@NapoleonWilson Got it—thanks for clarifying! So this was a manual process that probably ended with the 2018 ID question ban. (That makes sense—I was curious how "inactivity" was even defined.) Would you consider turning your comment into an answer? It’d be great to have this confirmed directly.
